# pass enum to html.radiobuttonfor MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I Have an Enum Called ActionStatus that has 2 possible values open=0 and closed = 1

```
public enum ActionStatus
{
    Open,
    Closed
}
```

I want to build radio button group in my edit and create views that uses the enum to populate the radio buttons with a) a default value in the create view and b) the currently selected option in the edit view.

Do i need an extension method for this, and has anybody already created one?

EDIT: After Darins's answer below this is my Model class

```
namespace Actioner.Models
{
[MetadataType(typeof(MeetingActionValidation))]
public class MeetingAction
{
    [Key]
    public int MeetingActionId              { get; set; }       

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description  { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Review Date")]
    public DateTime ReviewDate       { get ;set; }

    public int Status{ get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int MeetingId             { get; set; }


    //public virtual Meeting Meeting { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActionUpdate> ActionUpdates { get; set; }

    public MeetingActionStatus ActionStatus { get; set; }

}

public enum MeetingActionStatus 
{
    Open,
    Closed
}
```

and this is my view

```
@model Actioner.Models.MeetingAction
@using Actioner.Helpers


<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
</div>
 <div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReviewDate)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">

 @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(x => x.ActionStatus)

</div>
```

And this is my create controller action

```
public virtual ActionResult Create(int id)
    {

        var meetingAction = new MeetingAction
        {
            MeetingId = id,
            ReviewDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
        };

        ViewBag.Title = "Create Action"; 

        return View(meetingAction);
    }
```

The enum displays fine in the view, but the currently selected option is not persisted to the database

Comment: Is there a way to retreive from resource file for Open & Close values? Ex:[Display(Name = "Open", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), Order = 0)] Open.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
        )
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            var names = Enum.GetNames(metaData.ModelType);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                var id = string.Format(
                    "{0}_{1}_{2}", 
                    htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, 
                    metaData.PropertyName, 
                    name
                );

                var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();
                sb.AppendFormat(
                    "<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label> {2}", 
                    id, 
                    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name), 
                    radio
                );
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You could also enforce a [generic constraint to an enum type](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/09/10/generic-constraints-for-enums-and-delegates.aspx) for this helper method.

and then:

Model:

```
public enum ActionStatus
{
    Open,
    Closed
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public ActionStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            Status = ActionStatus.Closed
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(x => x.Status)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: Why do you use a string builder? Just for ease of concatenation and formatting? It seems like a very un-MVC way to do things.

Comment: The link to Jon Skeet's blog post on enforcing a generic constraint to an enum type no longer works.

Comment: It took a few minutes to figure out the correct `using` statements to use for HtmlExtensions code, so I edited your answer to include them.  Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 10):

Just add labels for radiobuttons

```
    public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
    )
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        var names = Enum.GetNames(metaData.ModelType);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var name in names)
        {

            var description = name;

            var memInfo = metaData.ModelType.GetMember(name);
            if (memInfo != null)
            {
                var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
                if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0 )
                    description = ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
            }
            var id = string.Format(
                "{0}_{1}_{2}",
                htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
                metaData.PropertyName,
                name
            );

            var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();
            sb.AppendFormat(
                "<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label> {2}",
                id,
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(description),
                radio
            );
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

and the Model:

```
    public enum MeetingActionStatus                   
{

    [Display(Name = "Open meeting")]
    Open,

    [Display(Name = "Closed meeting")]
    Closed             
}
```

Comment: The use of on the model and in the extension of the `Display` attribute is quite useful as often times the enums description is not usable for actually displaying in its raw format.

Comment: I am getting a error - 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>' does not contain a definition for 'RadioButtonFor' and no extension method 'RadioButtonFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>'

Comment: Try "using System.Web.Mvc.Html;"