# How do I use Html.EditorFor to render radio buttons in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model

Here's my model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "I'm a:")]
public bool Sex { get; set; }
```

And my editor template:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Sex)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Sex)
</div>
```

However this render to the following:

```
<div>
    <label for="RegisterModel_Sex">Soy:</label>
    <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Soy: field is required." id="RegisterModel_Sex" name="RegisterModel.Sex" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RegisterModel.Sex" type="hidden" value="false" />
</div>
```

How would I render some nice radio buttons for Male and Female? What datatype would my model have to have?

---

## Edit:

Here's my new updated code:

```
//Model:
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Soy:")]
    public Gender Sex { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

//Viewmodel:

<fieldset>
    <legend>Informacion Personal</legend>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Nombre)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Nombre)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Apellido)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Apellido)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Sex)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Sex)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Carnet)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegisterModel.Carnet)
    </div>    
</fieldset>


//EditorTemplate:

@model GoldRemate.WebUI.Models.Gender

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Gender";
}

<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="@Model" />
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary
> requires a non-null model item of type
> 'GoldRemate.WebUI.Models.Gender'.

What is causing this and how can I show the values of my enum in my form?

Comment: Have you created an editor template following the naming format? AKA did you create a `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Sex.ascx` file with how you want it rendered?

Comment: No, I didn't. Should I? Should it be named EXACTLY the same as my property?

Comment: Your model is *effectively* asking the question "Sex: Yes or no?" You're getting a checkbox because boolean fields are by default rendered as checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your property name. The editor template should correspond to your data type; in this case bool. I would suggest changing that to an `Enum`, and then making an editor template for that enum.

Comment: @Tejs: Would you mind showing me an example of how to setup a model containing an Enum with it's annotations? As an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create an enum like so:

```
 public enum Gender
 {
     Male = 1,
     Female = 2
 }
```

I'd alter your model slightly like so:

```
 public Gender Sex { get; set; }
```

And then in your view you would do this:

```
 Html.EditorFor(x => x.RegisterModel.Sex);
```

Then you would have an EditorTemplate here:

```
 ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Gender.cshtml
```

Which would have content like so:

```
@model EditorTemplate.Models.Gender // switch to your namespace

@Html.LabelFor(x => x, "Male")
@if(Model == EditorTemplate.Models.Gender.Male)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)EditorTemplate.Models.Gender.Male, new { @checked = "checked" });
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)EditorTemplate.Models.Gender.Male);
}

@Html.LabelFor(x => x, "Female")
@if(Model == EditorTemplate.Models.Gender.Female)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)EditorTemplate.Models.Gender.Female, new { @checked = "checked" });
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)EditorTemplate.Models.Gender.Female);
}
```

So I modeled this in Visual Studio, and this works as expected. Try it out.

Comment: Ok, so I've made you changes but I'm still getting stuck on the editor bit. In my editor template, what HTML would I need to write in in order to display each enum from the enum as a radio button? I've tried this but it doesn't work: `<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="@Model" />`

Comment: Please see my new edit for relevant things I've tried and how they didn't work.

Comment: When I try this I get duplicate IDs which isn't valid HTML.

Comment: I tried this approach but the VS scaffolding is generating @Html.EnumDropDownListFor...  EDIT Just noticed this is 2015