# MVC 5 checking RadioButtonFor based on model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem for which I just can't find a solution.

Checking button like this works:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.an2[0], 3, Model.an2[0]==3 
    ? new { id = "B", @checked = "checked" } : null)
```

But I also need to set id, how do I do that? This code:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.an2[0], 3, Model.an2[0]==3 
    ? new { id = "B", @checked = "checked" } : new { id = "B" })
```

Gives error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'AnonymousType#1' and 'AnonymousType#2'

Which is beyond my understanding.

I suppose there should be a trivial solution to this?

Comment: While Sam Farajpour Ghamari's answer shows you how to create conditional html attributes, it is completely unnecessary in your case. You should never set the `checked` attribute when using `RadioButtonFor()`. The helper already sets it based on the value if the property your binding to (and if its not, then you have other problems with your code)

Comment: I tried and it doesen't work in my case.

What I'm trying to create is a test, where user switches through partialviews and selects the answer he/she thinks is correct. If going to previous partialview I want that previously selected answer (radiobutton) is checked, but can be changed.

With my code and Sam's correction, the wanted effect takes place. If I remove the "checked" part it does not, even though the model that contains an2 list is passed back and forth.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong in your code, so perhaps you should also consider addressing that as well ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast them to `object`:

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.an2[0], 3, Model.an2[0]==3 
    ? (object)new { id = "B", @checked = "checked" } : (object)new { id = "B" });
```

Comment: That works! I didn't even know casting can be done in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320172/use-html-radiobuttonfor-and-html-labelfor-for-the-same-model-but-different-value).

```
@{string id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("radioTrue");}
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.an2[0], 3, Model.an2[0]==3 ? new { id } : null)
```

A good example of this is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611175/Radio-Buttons-for-List-Items-in-MVC-Problem-with).