# Razor: RadioButtonFor enum and displaying selected item in a summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, enums, razor, radiobuttonfor

I am using `RadioButtonFor` to display a list of selectable items. It's part of a wizard I am using, and the last step of the wizard is a summary for the user to confirm their submission. I have everything working except for the `RadioButtonFor`. My summary contains something pretty basic showing what the user input.

Example:

```
...

<div>Summary</div>

<div>Please confirm the information you are submitting.</div>

<div>First Name: @Model.FirstName</div>

...
```

The relevant portion of my model:

```
public CategoryList Category { get; set; }

public enum CategoryList
{
    Category1
    Category2
    Category3
}
```

The relevant portion of my page (wizard step with RadioButtonFor):

```
...

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category, new { @class = "CLASS" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)

<div>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Category, "Category1")
<span>NEW!</span>Category 1. This Category is for BLAH BLAH BLAH ...
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Category, "Category2")
Category 2. This Category is for BLAH BLAH BLAH ...
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Category, "Category3")
Category 3. This Category is for BLAH BLAH BLAH ...
</div>
...
```

The relevant portion of my page (wizard summary step containing RadiouButtonFor):

```
<div>@Model.Category</div>
```

The above simply displays the actual name in Category List, say "Category1" if the user selected Category 1, so I know I have the enum working correctly.  However, I want the description to be, well, more descriptive.  Say that I want Category1 to say "Category 1. This category is for BLAH BLAH BLAH" as well as to maybe put a  around "Category 1." So that it is displayed in RED. The actual name I use in the enum is three words, and contains two underscores, so it's not very UI friendly to have "Word1_Word2_Word3" in there, which is what displays in the summary.

To be more precise, if you look at the relevant portion of the page above which contains the `RadioButtonFor`, I include text for the radio button which shows to the user on the UI. The text that appears there is what I want to appear in the summary.

I tried using the following:

```
<div>@Model.Category.CategoryList</div>
```

but it throws an error (...does not contain a definition for "CategoryList" and no extension method "CategoryList" accepting a first argument of type ... could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference"). I've spent hours on the googlenet, and could not find anything (quite possibly because I am not formulating good search terms).

Any thoughts?  Is this possible, or is there something alternative I can do to achieve what I am looking for?

Again, I appreciate any help and sorry if re-asking in a different way is against policy.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with deleting and re-asking a poorly-formulated question.  However, your question is still unclear.

Comment: Not sure how you mean.  I am basically trying to show a summary page with the user input.  If user picks RadioButton 1, and I am using an ENUM, it will only display the name in the ENUM. I want it to display text that I describe for whatever RadioButton is selected, rather than what is in the ENUM. Sorry if not too clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store the descriptions in a `Dictionary<CategoryList, string>` somewhere and write `@Html.Raw(YourDictionary[Model.Category])`

Comment: Ah! I found something on the googlenet about the Dictionary<> but could not implement it properly.  Also, that @Html.Raw portion was not part of what I found, so that may actually get it to work.  Hopefully I can create that. Thanks! Will report back on my results.

Comment: I am getting the "YourDictionary" name doesn't exist in the current context here (where "YourDictionary") is the name of my dictionary.

Comment: If the dictionary is a static property, you need to access it through its containing class.

Comment: That last comment led me in the right direction. Problem was I ignored intellisence, which had me insert the ENTIRE thing of Namepace.Models.ViewModel.Class.Dictionary.  But that all did the trick, and now I can see the content of the dictionary.  Thanks!

Comment: You may want to `@using` the namespace.

Comment: This is a proper solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621013/pass-enum-to-html-radiobuttonfor-mvc3