# Adding control id dynaically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 with Razor.

I would like to generate id's for my radio button dynaically. I am calling my code in loop and the id's / name's should be generated dynaically.
Name to my radiobutton in my View...like below code....

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClaimEntity.Claim, "True", Model.m.ClaimEntity.Claim.Equals(true) ? new { name = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), id = "Claim", title = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString() } : null)
                @Html.Label("Yes")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClaimEntity.Claim, "False", Model.m.ClaimEntity.Claim.Equals(false) ? new { name = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), id = "Claim", title = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString() } : null)
                @Html.Label("No")
```

Problem is, the above code snippet does not show the dynamic id created for radiobutton whereas it shows the "title" created dynaimically, so I need something on similar line for "title" for "id" and "name" attribute.

Plz suggest how can i get this working.
Regards,

Comment: Here is some good guidance for using enums with radio buttons: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5621013/109941

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the radiobuttons you're generating have the same id! This can cause unexpected behavior in your webpage: as a rule, each element must have a *unique* id.

If we make the id dependent on ViewData["count"] as well, we can make sure they're unique.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClaimEntity.Claim, "True", Model.m.ClaimEntity.Claim.Equals(true) ? new { name = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), id = "Claim_True" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), title = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString() } : null)
                @Html.Label("Yes")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ClaimEntity.Claim, "False", Model.m.ClaimEntity.Claim.Equals(false) ? new { name = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), id = "Claim_True" + ViewData["count"].ToString(), title = "Claim_" + ViewData["count"].ToString() } : null)
                @Html.Label("No")
```