# @Html.RadioButtonFor and Editing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

the `@Html.RadioButtonFor` always confuses me right now I have in a ViewModel a property of an enum(lets say DayOfWeek as it is built in)

```
public class VM
{
    public DayOfWeek  SelectedDayOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

in my view I have

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vm.SelectedDayOfWeek,false, new {@id = "Sun"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vm.SelectedDayOfWeek,false, new {@id = "Mon"})
```

Now this works but how do I get it to work for editing. For instance they want to edit the day of week they set. I want to show them which option they choose.

How could I do this. As you see right now it is hardcoded to false.

Don't really want to do this

```
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vm.SelectedDayOfWeek,@SelectedSunValue, new {@id = "Sun"})
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vm.SelectedDayOfWeek,@SelectedMonValue, new {@id = "Mon"})
```

Comment: See selected answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621013/pass-enum-to-html-radiobuttonfor-mvc3?rq=1

Comment: you can also do it with client side jquery if you can update fine and the problem is just display