# ASP.NET MVC and multiple checkboxes for several properties, how to do that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool First {get;set;}
    public bool Second {get;set;}
    public bool Third {get;set;}
}
```

Now, i want to generate something, that will display this:

```
First - [checkbox] 
Second - [checkbox] 
Third - [checkbox]
[Submit]
```

And i want those checkboxes to select only one item from those properties, how can i do it?

**Edit: Sorry guys, i don't really need checkboxes, what i need is radiobuttons for that. If someone has any example code that shows how to solve my problem using radiobuttons, i would be grateful.**

Comment: Mutually exclusive checkboxes are not standard in any HTML framework. You should use javascript for achieving that. Otherwise, use radiobuttons.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want one of the items (First, Second or Third) to be selected. For this behavior use a radiobutton. Checkboxes allow each item to be selected regardless if the other item is selected. A radiobutton will only allow one of the items to be selected at a time.

Comment: Oh, you are right, i need radiobuttons! But anyways i don't know how to use them either, gonna google that now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer your question about checkboxes:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.First, "First -") @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.First)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.First, "Second -") @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Second)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.First, "Third -") @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Third)
```

Wrapping the text and the checkbox, allow the user to click in the label and select/deselect the check box.  Or, instead of wrapping the checkbox and text with a label, just use `LabelFor`.

Now... to accomplish that the user should check only one of those, please use a RadioButtons for that.

See the more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5621200/7720

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the "CheckBoxFor" Html helper and bind to each property.  Then, when you post, you can call TryUpdateModel() on your model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @HtmlHiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <div>First - @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.First)</div>
    <div>Second - @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Second)</div>
    <div>Third - @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Third)</div>
    <input type="submit">
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(int id)
{
    var model = new MyClass(); // build your model however you like
    TryUpdateModel(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RadioButtonFor. You will need only one property in your model.

Model:

```
public byte MyOption { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => model.MyOption, 1) 1
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => model.MyOption, 2) 2
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => model.MyOption, 3) 3
```