# Radio Button is readonly using Enums?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, html, asp.net-mvc-4

While developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 application, I have followed the answer on [pass enum to html.radiobuttonfor MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621013/pass-enum-to-html-radiobuttonfor-mvc3) and the answer from which it was derived, but my problem remains.

I am creating an edit page, and want to display Status as two radio buttons "Active" and "InActive", these values are read from the database as Enums  1 = Active , 2 = InActive.

The problem is, when the page is displayed it show's the correct radio button selected corresponding to the database value, but will not allow the user to change/select the other radio button ??

Any idea's, it's driving me nuts 
(also changing the property to a bool for a chkbox will cause more problems than it will solve at this point. )

Controller.....

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(NewsArticle newsArticle, int id, HttpPostedFileBase Article)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

             NewsArticle savedArticle= _newsArticle.Get(id);

             savedArticle.Body = newsArticle.Body;
             savedArticle.Title = newsArticle.Title;
             savedArticle.Status = newsArticle.Status;

             if(Article == null)
             {
                 newsArticle.ArticleImage = savedArticle.ArticleImage;
             }
             else
             {
                 using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
                 {
                     newsArticle.ArticleImage = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
                 }

                 savedArticle.ArticleImage = newsArticle.ArticleImage;

                 string imgeName = Path.GetFileName(Article.FileName);

                 savedArticle.ImageName = imgeName;

             }



             _uow.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

View..........

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="editor-field">
        <label class="control-label">Select Status :</label>
        <div class="controls">

            @Html.RadioButtonForEnum(n => n.Status)

               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Helper/extension.....

```
      public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForEnum<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
        )
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

            var names = Enum.GetNames(metaData.ModelType);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                var description = name;

                var memInfo = metaData.ModelType.GetMember(name);
                if (memInfo != null)
                {
                    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
                    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                        description = ((DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
                }

                var id = string.Format(
                    "{0}_{1}_{2}",
                    htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
                    metaData.PropertyName,
                    name
                );

                var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, name, new { id = id }).ToHtmlString();
                sb.AppendFormat(
                    "<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label> {2}",
                    id,
                    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name),
                    radio
                );
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
```

The helper is displaying labels as it should having being called from the view.

Enum....

```
     [Flags]
public enum NewsArticleStatus
{
    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    Active = 1,

    [Display(Name = "InActive")]
    Inactive = 2
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the enum have to have the `[Flags]` attribute? I'd interpret that to mean `Active` AND `Inactive` (= `3`) would be a valid value...

Comment: No, your right that could be removed.

Comment: Sorry to not be of much help otherwise. Hmm... could it be that when the user tries to select the other radiobutton, the page get's refreshed and re-selects the value from the database? Meaning that some onChanged method should set the value, so when the page refreshes, the set value will be taken and not the one from the database.

Comment: Not at all, thanks for taking the time, I don't think so as the current value according to the database is selected when page is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it....

Added my original model(Article) to a viewModel and Added a bool property.... Active..

```
      public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Article != null)
            {
                return (this.Article.Status == NewsArticleStatus.Active);
            }
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Article != null)
            {
                this.Article.Status = (value ? NewsArticleStatus.Active : NewsArticleStatus.Inactive);
            }
        }
    }
```

Create the chkbox....

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(n => n.Active)
```

So in the Controller simply assign the value to the new model

```
 newNews.Status = model.Article.Status;
```